# How to prevent new circles to be created whenever the circle's center changes. (Google Maps API)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, google-maps-markers, directions

I'm creating a web app that shows the closest location to a user's current position and the route to take. The problem is that I am using a simple circle animation to display the user location in the map and every time the user's position changes it creates a new circle.

```
    var circle;
    var smallCircle;

    function getLocation() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition);
      } else {
        alert("Sorry the geolocation failed");
      }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
        const pos =
        {
       lat: position.coords.latitude,
       lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
       console.log(pos);
       locationMarker(pos);
    }

    function locationMarker(user){

     if (smallCircle != null & circle != null) {


          circle.setCenter(user);
          smallCircle.setCenter(user);
          map.panTo(user);

        } else {

          smallCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
             center: user,
             radius: 5,
             strokeColor: "#1abc9c",
             strokeOpacity: 1,
             strokeWeight: 1,
             fillColor: "#1abc9c",
             fillOpacity: 0.5
          });

          circle = new google.maps.Circle({
             center: user,
             radius: 20,
             strokeColor: "#1abc9c",
             strokeOpacity: 1,
             strokeWeight: 1,
             fillColor: "#1abc9c",
             fillOpacity: 0.5
          });

          circle.setMap(map);
          smallCircle.setMap(map);

          // This is the animation
          var direction = 0.8;
          var rMin = 5, rMax = 20;
          setInterval(function() {
              var radius = circle.getRadius();
              if ((radius > rMax) || (radius < rMin)) {
                  direction *= -1;
              }
              circle.setRadius(radius + direction * 0.4);
              }, 50);

        }
    }
```

I have tried an if statement to declare that in case there is already a circle it should change the center (position) of it. Otherwise, it should create a new one.

I expect to create only one circle animation and that it can re-center every time the user changes its position but right now it's creating a new circle when changing position.

*Update
Now that I've removed the circle parameters from the function it's working. :)

Comment: you have a typo in your code: `locationMarker(pos)` should be `locationMarker(pos, circle, smallCircle)` where you call it.  With your current code `circle` and `smallCircle` will **always** be null.

Comment: Thank you I've already updated it with your feedback but still the same issue keeps happening.

Answer (score 1):

<s>The function where you draw your circles seems to accept the circles as parameters.</s>

```
function locationMarker(user, circle, smallCircle)
```

But when you actually call this function the `showPosition` function, you're only passing it the user location.

```
locationMarker(pos);
```

Because of this, the function parameters `circle` and `smallCircle` will be null, and because it's within the scope of the function, they'll get 'priority' over the global `circle` and `smallCircle` variables declared at the top of the script.

**EDIT:** The example has been updated so that `circle` and `smallCircle` are now passed to the function, but there's still a problem. When you create the circles and assign them to `circle` and `smallCircle`, you're assigning *to the parameters* of the function which are completely separate from the global circles declared at the top. Once the function goes out of scope, those the parameters disappear and the global variables are untouched.

**Solution:** remove the circle parameters from the function and rely solely on the global variables

```
function locationMarker(user)
```